# Tool for checking and repair FAT32, NTFS, exFAT, HFS and HFS+ file systems under Linux OS Family

Tags: linux, disk-analysis, repair, filesystems

fsck.vfat (dosfsck) can check FAT32, but can't repair most of the errors.

ntfsfix can check, but to repair often suggest to use Windows and chkdsk from it.

I don't know how to check and repair another file system from the title in Linux.

I don't have MS Windows or Mac OS X, but I need two Linux good tools, maybe non-free:

1. For checking and repair FAT32, NTFS, exFAT (Windows's standard fs).
2. For checking and repair HFS and HFS+ (Mac OS X's standard fs).

Or maybe one tool for all.

[testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) supports FAT, exFAT, NTFS, but it is not automatic repair tool and can't fix most of the errors.

[photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) even supports HFS+, but it can't repair fs, it can only repair files from it.

First of all, I need a full featured fs auto repair tool (maybe with some user confirmations) as in the title.

Comment: You can download a Windows ISO file for free, and install it for a 30-day trial period with 3 (4?) times to rearm the trial time. After that the only thing is the black wallpaper, most other features remain normally functioning. But you don't need to install the OS, just boot the windows installer and select repair

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc And how windows installer can help me with HFS/HFS+?

Comment: you said that you need 2 good tools, not necessarily one tool for all

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Then... Where is your proposed tool for HFS/HFS+?

Comment: for that you need to ask another person

Answer (score 0):

GParted uses a range of tools (some I think are inbuilt, but most probably rely on external utilities (e.g `ntfsprogs`). It is packaged and included in most Linux distros.

As far as I can tell it can support checking and repairing FAT32, NTFS and HFS+. FAT32 and NTFS both can be fixed - with NTFS I think there is a flag set so that if a Windows system accesses it checks it itself before using it.

ExFAT support is still limited in Linux, but there appears to be [`exfatfsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/fsck.exfat.8.html) which can scan for errors but can't fix them.

HFS and HFS+ support is available, but I think only HFS+ can be fixed in some way as it can journalling filesystem, (Not sure here as I don't use Macs etc)

When it is installed,  you can check what it supports using the [Filesystem Support Window](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-usage):

[image: Filesystem support window screenshot]

More information can be found [here](http://gparted.org/index.php), and more screen-shots can be found [here](http://gparted.org/screenshots.php)

Comment: Of course I know about GParted. But GParted uses fsck.vfat (dosfsck) and ntfsfix. Checking and reparing of HFS and HFS+ is not full too. Checking and reparing of exfat is impossible for GParted. So, your answer can't help me.